# jQuery autopopulate fields - math based

Tags: javascript, jquery, field

I'm just starting out with jQuery and JS. I'm trying to set the downpayment field and the principle field dynamically based on the other fields but the downpayment and the principle field can be manually set. They just have to add up to the Estimated Value/Appraisal field. There is also weird behaviour where if I enter a value in a field with an autopopulated field, it retains it's original value. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/wccznmr3/

```
//autocalculate downpayment
function computeD (){
    var value = $("#edit-field-estimated-value-und-0-value").val();
    var appraised = $("#edit-field-appraisal-amount-und-0-value").val();
    var mort1 = $("#edit-field-1st-mortgage-und-0-value").val();
    var princ = $("#edit-field-amount-new-und-0-value").val();
    var down = $("#edit-field-down-payment-und-0-value").val();

    function realVal () {
        var propValue;
        if (appraised === ""){
            propValue = value;
        } else {
            propValue = appraised;
        }
        return propValue;
    }

    var princP = realVal() - mort1 - down;
    var downP = realVal() - mort1 - princ;

    $("#edit-field-down-payment-und-0-value").val(downP);
    $("#edit-field-amount-new-und-0-value").val(princP);
}

//autocalculate down payment based on mort1 and princ
$("#edit-field-estimated-value-und-0-value,#edit-field-appraisal-amount-und-0-value, #edit-field-1st-mortgage-und-0-value,#edit-field-amount-new-und-0-value,#edit-field-down-payment-und-0-value").change(computeD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a change is made to the Principle and Down Payment input fields, the function which determines the value of the Principle and Down Payment input fields is invoked and their values are overwritten:

```
var princP = realVal() - mort1 - down;
var downP = realVal() - mort1 - princ;

$("#edit-field-down-payment-und-0-value").val(downP);
$("#edit-field-amount-new-und-0-value").val(princP);
```

So when a user manually changes these fields, computeD() is called, and their changes get overwritten.  If you don't want the values to be re-computed, don't call computeD() when the values of these fields are changed:

```
//autocalculate down payment based on mort1 and princ
$("#edit-field-1st-mortgage-und-0-value, #edit-field-appraisal-amount-und-0-value, #edit-field-estimated-value-und-0-value").change(computeD);
```

Futher, you can use the `disabled` attribute to make sure that they can't change the values of the fields manually (if this is what you are intending):

```
<input class="text-full form-text required" type="text" id="edit-field-amount-new-und-0-value" name="field_amount_new[und][0][value]" value="" size="10" maxlength="255" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I realize that the function is called each time there is a change but it's because I want to the updates to be live as the user types. I don't know how to do this and prevent the overwriting.

Also, I don't want to disable any of the fields.